# Encode/Decode (Encrypt/Decrypt) datetime var in vb6

Tags: encryption, vb6

I want to encode a datetime var into a 8-byte alphanumeric string that can be decoded later. I don't need too much security.

```
201603301639 -> X5AHY6J9
```

and viceversa.

Comment: It won't fit. `Date` data type requires 64 bits, but you only have somewhat less than 48 bits of space (assuming upper and lowercase and digits 0-9).

Comment: I could not cosider date and encoding only time, i. e. "1247".

Answer (score 0):

The highest date value in numerical form `999912312359` fits in a Double and when converted to Base36 would output string of `"CRCPZ21Z"` which meets your requirement.

Using the encoder function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36#Visual_Basic_implementation) and this decoder:

```
Function base36decode(ByRef base36 As String) As Double
    Const alphabet As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    base36decode = InStr(1, alphabet, Right(base36, 1), vbTextCompare) - 1
    For i = Len(base36) - 1 To 1 Step -1
        base36decode = base36decode + 36 ^ (Len(base36) - i) * (InStr(1, alphabet, Mid(base36, i, 1)) - 1)
    Next i
End Function
```

You can:

```
x = ConvertBase10(999912312359, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
?x
CRCPZ21Z

?base36decode((x))
 999912312359
```

This is encoding, not encryption. For *weak obfuscation* simply switch the order of characters in the alphabet string each routine uses or perform some arbitrary arithmetic on the input value.